# SlideShowExtractor NoSuchMethodError org.apache.poi.sl.usermodel.Sheet.getPlaceholderDetails

Tags: apache-poi

Trying to use POI 4.0.1 to extract text from powerpoints. Using all POI 4.0.1 jars and getting a method not found exception

> Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.apache.poi.sl.usermodel.Sheet.getPlaceholderDetails(Lorg/apache/poi/sl/usermodel/Placeholder;)Lorg/apache/poi/sl/usermodel/PlaceholderDetails;
>           at org.apache.poi.sl.extractor.SlideShowExtractor.addSheetPlaceholderDatails(SlideShowExtractor.java:224)
>           at org.apache.poi.sl.extractor.SlideShowExtractor.printHeaderReturnFooter(SlideShowExtractor.java:183)
>           at org.apache.poi.sl.extractor.SlideShowExtractor.printShapeText(SlideShowExtractor.java:236)
>           at org.apache.poi.sl.extractor.SlideShowExtractor.getText(SlideShowExtractor.java:130)
>           at org.apache.poi.sl.extractor.SlideShowExtractor.getText(SlideShowExtractor.java:120)

Looked at my classpath and didn't find mismatched or duplicate poi jars. Poked around in the POI 4 distribution jars and could not find the missing method

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream( file.getPath() );
XMLSlideShow xmlA = new XMLSlideShow( fis );
SlideShowExtractor<XSLFShape, XSLFTextParagraph> ex = new SlideShowExtractor<>( xmlA );

String text = ex.getText();
```

Comment: Am I right that your code compiles without errors but throws `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError` on runtime? If so, you definitely must have `apache poi` jars lower than version `4.0.1` in class path while run time. Please check runtime class path again. The `org.apache.poi.sl.usermodel.Sheet` is contained in `poi-4.0.1.jar`. So please check you only have `poi-*4.0.1.jar`s in class path while runtime and no other `poi-*.jar`s from versions lower than `4.0.1`.

Comment: I thought that it was a classpath issue but couldn't figure out how since I had no other poi jars. Turned out that the tika-app jar embeds poi (or some subsets of it) and tika was on the classpath.

Comment: Of course you should stay actual with **all** libraries. [Apache Tika 1.20](https://tika.apache.org/1.20/index.html) - "Upgrade to Apache POI 4.0.1".